# is PDO::PARAM_INT redundant?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Does `PDO::PARAM_INT` perform any function at all when used with `$db->quote()` function? e.g. `$db->quote($user['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT)`?

It seems like it is, because even string input will get passed trough. Not to mention that it keeps the quotes around the integer. Is there any reason why should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no effect, since, after all, you *are* running the `quote` function. It's only natural that it gets wrapped in quotes. `PDO::PARAM_INT` is likely more important in other contexts, like prepared statements, where it is actually handled differently than strings.

`quote` likely is more concerned with other data types that should not be quoted or should be quoted differently, like `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`

Comment: Would I be wrong though if I'd extend PDO instance's `quote` method to NOT escape, though make sure the input is integer if `PDO::PARAM_INT` is provided?

Comment: @Guy: I mean, you could, but I'm not sure why to bother with it. No database engine is going to have a big problem with it being quoted. Keep your job as easy as possible :)

Comment: What about this specific example https://gist.github.com/4e0897133b4ce5b5855e It will create more than 10k records. Wouldn't the quotes around the integer have a great effect? (the original example had every parameter of the query surrounded with `db->quote`.)

Comment: @Guy: Dunno. Benchmark it. If you're actually running 10k queries in one go, maybe the optimization is worthwhile. I suspect, though, that your project has other places where you should look first if you're interested in shaving off those few precious seconds.